# How do we use spring jdbctemplate in scala programming

Tags: java, scala, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm new scala programming. How do we use the spring jdbctemplate in scala class ?

Comment: did my answer help? - please add a comment or accept the answer - so it will help others and gives me some feedback

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is to inject it, here an example within Play (Guice):

```
class DataRepository @Inject()(val jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate)
```

Then you can use it like you would in Java:

```
  val query =
    """select directory_id,name,parent_id,type from directory
       where parent_id is null and type = :dirType"""
  val params = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("dirType", dirType)
  val result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, params, DBDirData())
```

The result however you have to bring in the Scala world:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

result.asScala.headOption
```